# Compliance / Conformance Testing software for NTFS permissions?

Tags: automated-testing, files

Is there a software standard for Compliance / Conformance Testing of NTFS permissions, that you could run before an audit to see if everything has the permissions as expected, and if not that would report failures?

I'm interested in this for purposes of [PCI DSS compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pci_security/glossary).

Might the software also have templates that can be applied to various web platforms / web servers and their plugins such as Wordpress or Joomla?

Answer (score 1):

Frankly for automation you would have to program it all yourself, but you can record things through an automation tool and then kick it off again.  Sikuli is free and does image recognition with entered keys.  This allows you to hit any command line window including remote machines etc...anything that displays and then execute various commands and get expected results.  You can run through your security checks via command line and ensure the proper response is sent back.

Optionally you can code it via scripting in various server side languages and execute that way.  As far as anything else it's usually a combination of penetration testing and setup/config items depending on what you actually have setup and therefore it's a little custom for every setup even though the same standards are utilized.  There may be a product to purchase out there, but I haven't seen one that ensures overall compliance and not specialized for pen testing etc...

No silver bullet, but perhaps that will help you start to build your own.  If you have more specifics you are targeting instead of just "general compliance" please add that to the example.